# Converting oracle sql script to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, phpmyadmin

Hi  I'm looking to convert part of my oracle sql script into mysql script.

The part that I'm converting is as follows:

```
create table inspection
(property_no number(5) not null references prop_for_rent(property_no),
staff_no number(5) not null references staff(staff_no),
inspect_date date,
comments varchar2(50),
primary key(property_no,staff_no,inspect_date))
```

I have started to convert  just having difficulty with the primary key  which throws an error  #1062 - Duplicate entry for primary key when inserting into the db. image link  below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfVW9.png

Comment: If you change `number` to `numeric` and `varchar2` to `varchar` it should work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb695e

Comment: That error should occur when you insert data into the table. It should not occur when creating the table.

Comment: yes  the error does show when I am inserting records :                                              `insert into inspection
values(1003,201,'12-JUN-2012','Cracked sink in kitchen requires repair');
MySQL said: Documentation

#1062 - Duplicate entry '1003-201-0000-00-00' for key 'PRIMARY`

Comment: my inserts that I need:`insert into inspection
values(1001,201,'12-JUN-2010','No problems');
insert into inspection
values(1002,201,'13-JUN-2010','Crockery needs to be replaced');
insert into inspection
values(1003,201,'12-JUN-2009','Broken window pane requires urgent repair');
insert into inspection
values(1006,203,'21-MAR-2010','No problems');
insert into inspection
values(1007,203,'01-DEC-2010','Sofa trim pulled apart by cat. Repair needed');
insert into inspection
values(1003,201,'12-JUN-2012','Cracked sink in kitchen requires repair');`

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that the values of the `inspect_date` column that were inserted are zero dates  `'0000-00-00'` and that's because the value provided in the INSERT statement `'12-JUN-2010'` is not a valid format for a date value in MySQL.

In MySQL, we could do this:

```
... VALUES(1001,201,STR_TO_DATE('12-JUN-2010','%d-%b-%Y'),'No  problems')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or this:

```
... VALUES(1001,201,'2010-06-12','No  problems')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```